# c99 Mode for Single Files in for Code::Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks, c99

I am having problems compiling some code I am working on. I have recently decided to learn C so I can get a better understanding of low level languages. I tried to make a for loop, but it returns the error that I cannot make declarations within the loop without `c99 mode`. I went into `Settings>Compiler>Other Settings` and added `-std=c99`, but it still does not work. The file is not in a project, as I will be making many files, each with a main, which the compiler prevents me from doing for multiple declarations of main. I also know that it is possible to declare outside the array, but I'd rather figure out how to solve this problem. I am using `Code::Blocks 12.11`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show the complete compiler command line you're using?

Comment: All it has is -std=c99, the rest of the box was blank.

Comment: That's just a flag.  Somewhere, your IDE must have a log of what commands it's actually running.  Can you get one and paste it here?

Comment: ftr: C is a **high**level language :)

Comment: Hmm. I always thought it was a low level language. I guess that is more in comparison to C++ or Java, which I have also used.

Answer (score 2):

Goto Project->Properties->Build Targets->Build Options->Compiler Settings->Other Options and add `-std=c99` to the current configuration (debug or release)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the solution, it seems to be working. I was adding the line in the dialog that was directly in the Other Settings menu, not the command line dialog box under the Advanced Settings menu from within Other Settings. It seems to work fine now. Thanks for the advice, I will use it in future!